# "mobx-react" package is deprecated?

Tags: reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

mobx-react Now not recommended to use?

https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-react

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As README says  `This repo has been moved to mobx`

https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx/ is now monorepo with all the packages, so nothing is deprecated.